# javascript-php var post get

Tags: php, javascript

That code work:

```
startSlideshow(<?php echo json_encode(glob("photos-animaux/*.jpg"))?>);
```

that code dont :

```
$.post("",{'folder':'animaux'});
startSlideshow(<?php echo json_encode(glob("photos-".$_GET["folder"]."/*.jpg"))?>);
```

WHY ?, what i am doing wrong ?, help !
why the stupid php fonction just dont make the string right !! ahhhh!

---new infos----
that line work :

```
startSlideshow(<?php echo json_encode(glob("photos-".$_GET["folder"]."/*.jpg")) ?>);
```

because if i MANUALLY enter in the address bar ?folder=animaux...bam! work

so the problem shoul be there : $.get("photo-portfolio.php",{folder:"animaux"});

still dont know where !

Comment: I don't understand your question. What is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using $.post() from JQuery, you should use $_POST['folder'] to access your variable.  If you use $.get(), then you use $_GET['folder'] in PHP.  Try changing that $_GET to $_POST.

Comment: i change it .... still dont work, but i think the problem is the jquery part.... because when manually enter ?folder=animaux.. it work

Comment: If ?folder=animaux works, this is a fine way to do it.  The preferred notation in JQuery for that though is $.get("",{'folder':'animaux'})

Answer (score 1):

Change `$_GET["folder"]` to `$_POST["folder"]` ?

You can dump the `$_POST` to be sure you're getting the right info..

```
echo '<pre>', print_r( $_POST, 1), '</pre>';
```

Comment: Are you sure you're posting to the right URI? Inspect this in Firebug and see where its going.

Comment: in fact the get variable is : undefine !

Answer (score 1):

I hope you're not literally writing these two lines together and hope they are interacting, are you?

```
$.post("",{'folder':'animaux'});
startSlideshow(<?php echo json_encode(glob("photos-".$_GET["folder"]."/*.jpg"))?>);
```

PHP runs on the server, Javascript in the browser. In the above two lines, if written like this, the PHP is already long done by the time `$.post()` is called.

PHP processes the code on the server and sends this to the browser:

```
$.post("",{'folder':'animaux'});
startSlideshow(['something.jpg', 'something2.jpg']);
```

The browser executes this code:

1. Post `{'folder':animaux'}` to `""` (no effect whatsoever).
2. Start a slideshow with `['something.jpg', 'something2.jpg']` (which was already decided by the time the page loaded).

I hope you're aware of this two stage process.

Comment: So, what you explain to me make perfect sense, so that bring the question to me, how do i execute a javascript funtion, that send var to php on run time ?

Comment: Do you really need to send the variable at runtime? Is it based on any user input? Or could everything be prepared already before the page loads? If you *do* need to talk to the server during runtime, you'll need to send an AJAX request to the server which will answer with a JSON or XML object which you can use in your Javascript. http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)